# How to use Wild card in where clause?

Tags: where-clause, wildcard, splunk

I am using below query to shunt `ORA-00001` from set of log files. this query works fine for just `one log file`.

```
index=xyz* NOT [search index=xyz* "ORA-00001" | WHERE source="/logs/sit/camel-audit.log"]
```

but when I put wild card in `where clause`, it doesn't work.

```
index=xyz* NOT [search index=xyz* "ORA-00001" | WHERE source="/logs/*/camel-audit.log"]
```

Could you please help me on how to use wild card in where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to take advantage of wildcards in Where clause, you can use LIKE operator for comparison.

Eg. `WHERE source LIKE "/logs/%/camel-audit.log"]`

Note that the equals operator does not support wildcard comparison.
Also note the use of '%' as a wildcard character instead of '*'. '%' denotes multiple characters.

This link - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp might be helpful.

Comment: @RandeepSingh - Can you please accept this as the answer if this worked for you?